# gedit 3 regex plugin

Tags: regex, fedora, gedit, gedit-plugin

Has anyone gotten a regex plugin to work in gedit 3 (Fedora 15)? I have tried 2 plugins so far:
http://halfhourhacks.blogspot.com/2008/03/gedit-regular-expression-plugin.html
http://code.google.com/p/yare-gedit-plugin/

For both, I tried installing to ~/.local/share/gedit/plugins/. According to https://live.gnome.org/Gedit/Plugins, this should be the correct location. For completeness, I have also tried installing to ~/.gnome2/gedit/plugins/, the location that worked for me in Ubuntu 10.10. Neither location produced any new search menu entries or any listings in Edit -> Preferences -> Plugins.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[advanced-find](http://code.google.com/p/advanced-find/) 3.0.0 beta supports gedit 3, you can have a try. (I'm still using gedit 2)

Answer (score 0):

I had to put the yare-gedit-plugin in the /usr/lib/gedit-2/plugins directory for it to work.  I think the ~/.local/share/gedit/plugins/ solution is for an older version.

It's working fine for me.  However, it looks like aleung's link is worth a try too.  There appears to be a bunch more options.

Comment: both should work, ~/.local is just for one user not for the system

Answer (score 0):

Some time ago, I forked this plugin and now I ported it to Gedit 3. You may find it [in this BitBucket page](https://bitbucket.org/brandizzi/gedit-re-search/). If you like the look-and-feel of the original Gedit Search and Replace dialog, you may like it.